# unmanaged c++ dll dependency not getting copied to application folder but different managed dll is

Tags: visual-studio, dependencies

I have a VS2010 C++ application with dendencies/references to two DLLs.  After building the application the managed dll, call it A, gets copied to the application folder from its library folder.  The other one, B,  does not.  I can delete A by hand rebuild and it always shows up.

I dread doing post build rules in B's vcxproj  because I will soon have a 2nd application that also needs references to B.

I have compared the Reference settings between DLL A and DLL B and they appear to have the same settings, (copy local = true, false, false, true, false)

Thanks all.

Comment: What's this "true, false, false, true, false" thing? You have two projects with only one property ("Copy Local"). Where are all those boolean values coming from?

Comment: Application Project Property Pages->Common Properties->Framework & References->Select Dependent DLL, Build Properties->Copy to Local = True, etc, etc, etc,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that references are set up in VS2010 makes it look like this should work, and it would be extremely useful if it did.  Unfortunately, Microsoft has pretty much made a policy of giving the finger to non-.NET developers since VS2005, and that trend continues with VS2010.  This issue was reported to [Microsoft.Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/561522/copylocal-not-working-in-vs-2010-for-unmanaged-projects) where they confirmed that they could reproduce it, then closed it as "by design."  So you probably will have to continue cobbling together an ugly set of post-build commands.